# I suspect that my HDD is causing hardlocks, as all other components have been replaced. How can I check this theory and solve the potential cause?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have had this problem over quite a while now, thorough multiple Linux kernel versions and distributions, as well as replacement of all components, aside from my main HDD - RAM, GPU(twice), mother board, CPU, power supply.

What happens is, at one point during the operation of the PC, it will hardlock - everything stops working, external HDD is not shut down correctly and continues to spin until I plug it out and in, there are no system/kernel logs of any kind, and no otherwise nothing that would suggest a cause.

Another reason for my suspicion is that the failures happen almost exclusively during HDD read/write activity - shutdown(happens nearly 1/3 of the time so far, it's only been few days though), launching programs, and once during operation of apt.

I hope the post is descriptive enough, if you need any additional info, ask(and tell me how to prepare/obtain it), and I will provide. If I'm wrong, point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Download the ISO version of mhdd 
burn it to a CD.
Boot the system from CD
Select the correct hard drive.
<F4> should bring up scan menu
toggle the second item down on (fix/relocate)
begin scan
```

wait......hours

Comment: It's DOS-based though... I guess it's good if it works, but aren't there any solutions perhaps Linux-based?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, right now I have no CD/DVD to burn, and as I live far from a city, obtaining some will take few days. With GRUB I could probably boot a Linux-based program off my HDD though.

Comment: Do you have a spare USB memory stick you can make bootable?

Comment: Oh, yeah, there's that possibility, I think I should have one.